# Can you make chickens follow you on the Xbox?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have the most recent version of Minecraft for the Xbox (v1.2), which allows one to make a chicken farm that won't despawn after moving too far away.  From my reading it seems that on the PC you can attract chickens using either seeds or wheat, depending on the version you are on.  I have attempted to use either to no success.  Am I not doing this right, or does this behaviour still not exist on the XBOX?

Answer (score 6):

I do not have a direct answer for your question, but based on what I learned [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breeding#Breeding_in_Xbox_Minecraft), breeding is not yet a part of the Xbox version.

This behaviour (following the player who is holding wheat) seems to stem from breeding, and thus it seems that it is not yet implemented.

Comment: The Xbox development is following (more or less) the beta development on PC; "attraction" mechanics that make animals follow you were part of the update with breeding, so it stands to reason that they will arrive in the same xbox update.

Answer (score 3):

On the PC version you can use seeds but it is not yet possible on the Xbox version as breeding has not been implemented yet.

Comment: But now you can breed them on the xbox version so chickens will follow you with seeds

Answer (score 2):

You can. Use wheat seeds. Hold the wheat seeds in your hand and find one then it should follow you. 
You can then make them breed 2 ways:

1. Get two chickens and have the wheat seeds in your hands. Put them where you want them because after having a baby, they don't follow you. So use the wheat seeds and press the LT button. (This puts an animal into love mode, do this to both) and there you have a baby.
2. Get chicken eggs. Throw them at the chickens. (Increases the chance of a baby coming out)
   This doesn't always work, you have an 75% chance of getting one.

Answer (score 1):

No chickens do not follow you, but their current coding makes them go towards grass and light. If you don't want to lose them dig a pit or make a fence and get them in there. if you have an egg you can throw it with LT it has a 1/32 chance of hatching, but it seems like better chances based on actual results. Also it has a 1/256 of hatching 4 chickens. Just a warning, it seems like there is a maximum number of chickens that can be in a world. I'm not sure how many exactly, but it seems to be about 50 give or take a couple. I personally have a farm of over 30 chickens, and in that same game, ny friend has over a5, all done in survival. (Next update animals will follow people holding wheat and you'll be able to breed them. also you'll get spawn eggs in creative mode.)

Comment: The chance of spawning a chicken by throwing an egg is 1/8 (source: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Chicken_Egg)

Answer (score -1):

, i've found today how to let them follow you , only ADULT chickens follow you when you have wheat SEEDs , then you can make them breed 2 ;)

Comment: Breeding chickens isn't available on Xbox, I was the one who disliked you.